# multiple (required) dhcp servers causes network problems in public library

Tags: networking, dhcp

A client of me asked me for helping with a network problem.
The client in question is a public library.

The problem:
The library provide wireless internet access to the guests via an all-in-one router provided and managed by the local telecom provider (later refered to as internet router).

For a service they provide they need to provide internet/network connection to an external managed accesspoint/router/all-in-one (later refered to as service router).
The service router gets it network connection via the wan port from the internet router.
This service router also unknowingly provide DHCP services on the main network, which is in this case a rouge DHCP.

We can't disable DHCP on both routers.

This causes that guests doesn't get internet access and the provided service doesn't work neither.

---

I can't realy say what kind of service is provided, but it does need an internet connection. and it needs the SR to provided an unprotected hidden network.

---

Proposed solutions:
I'm thinking about setting up a network topology where the network is split in 2 or 3 parts with a internal router

so:

Internet router

|

\ Main network

|

\ Service network

or something like this.

I don't know how to create such topologies, are there appliances for this or is it required to custom made this with Linux/Windows solutions?

---

For the information about the current appliances:

Currently I don't know what kind of appliance the service router is, I'll ask people who work at the library. We don't have access to the device

The internet router is an infamous KPN Experia box, locked down so we can't do much.

Comment: "We can't disable DHCP on both routers." - Well you only need to disable DHCP on one of the routers.

Comment: It would probably also help if you identified all of this equipment.

Comment: You cant disable them because you dont know how or dont have access to either router?

Comment: We don't have access to the service router, and the router provided by the telecom provider is locked down.

I don't know what kind of appliance the service router is.
The internet router is one of those infamous KPN experia boxes (dutch local telecom provider)

Answer (score 1):

So the service router has both LAN and WAN ports plugged into the "local network"? And the Internet Router has a LAN port connected to the "local network", and it's WAN is DSL/Cable/GSM/Whatever?

If that's the case the Service Router either needs to have it's DHCP disabled, or it needs to have it's LAN port disconnected from the "local network". I'm guessing however that it provides VPN access to some external service. In that case computers that need to be connected to that external service should be on a separate network that is connected to only that SR LAN port. In no case should a network be connected to both LAN ports of the SR and IR. If all computers need access, just daisy chain the routers (SR LAN to the "local network", SR WAN to IR LAN, IR WAN to whatever).

Comment: thanks for your reply. the IR provides the itnernet connection through DSL to the network. As mentioned above it is a locked down router under the brand KPN Experia Box (which are in fact multiple different routers with the same name). tWe don't have/want access to the SR since it isn't ours, but provided for the service. - The service needs to broadcast an unprotected wireless network and needs to have internet connection.

Comment: So both the IR and the SR provide WiFi access to the public?

Comment: Yes they both provide WiFi access. The IR router does it for the normal guests with a password provided when you are on premise. The SR router does it for providing a certain service for certain devices, it's a hidden network with a name known by those devices. (I don't have the liberty to tell what kind of device/service)

Comment: Ok, so where are the two LANs connected? I don't see where there would be a problem with this setup yet.

Comment: when the SR is connected with the main network, the clients on the main network DOESN'T have internet. - when we disconnect the SR the clients DOES have internet.

Comment: Did the SR come with directions as to how it should be connected?

Comment: the service provider did the setup, but like I said in the question, has some conflicts...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you *can't* disable DHCP on one of the routers, but a simple solution would be to change the DHCP scope/range of available IP addresses each router can lease.  For this, let's assume the public access is **router1** and the service access is **router2**

For example, **router1** can lease `192.168.0.50-192.168.0.100` and **router2** can lease `192.168.0.101-192.168.0.150`.  This should work for you, depending on how many clients need access to either network.

A more complex solution would be to create multiple subnets on your network.  This would be a better solution, since you can have the option to segregate the networks logically, and most of your **router1** traffic won't go into **router2** traffic and vice versa, unless intended.  It can also add a layer of security if you need it.

For example, **router1** can lease the entire `192.168.0.0/24` network, and **router2** can lease the entire `192.168.1.0/24` network.  To accomplish this, you would need to build static routes in your routers.

The following configs assume you're connecting the WAN from **router2** into a LAN port on the **router1** network.

Example **router1** config:

```
WAN: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
LAN: 192.168.0.1
LAN SUBNET: 255.255.255.0
LAN DHCP SCOPE: 192.168.0.0/24
LAN DHCP LEASABLE ADDRESSES:  192.168.0.2-192.168.0.253

STATIC ROUTES:
(NETWORK) 192.168.1.0/24  (SUBNET) 255.255.255.0 (GATEWAY) 192.168.0.254
```

Example **router2** config:

```
WAN: 192.168.0.254
LAN: 192.168.1.1
LAN SUBNET: 255.255.255.0
LAN DHCP SCOPE: 192.168.1.1/24
LAN DHCP LEASABLE ADDRESSES:  192.168.1.2-192.168.1.253

STATIC ROUTES:
(NETWORK) 192.168.0.0/24  (SUBNET) 255.255.255.0 (GATEWAY) 192.168.1.1
(NETWORK) 0.0.0.0/24 (SUBNET) 0.0.0.0 (GATEWAY) 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: We can't disable the DHCP because the public/internet router is locked down (and provided) by the telecom provider - we can't disable the DHCP because the service router is not owned by the library but provided by the service provider.

Comment: Then you'll need them to make the change for you.  If they won't make the change for you (I don't see why they wouldn't, if you're paying them to manage it), then it sounds like it's time to put your own equipment in place.  Otherwise, the rest of my answer above should suffice.